# Desktop environment that raises terminal with gnu-screen instead of starting new one

Tags: gnu-screen, gnome-terminal, .desktop

I want to start a gnu-`screen` session, in a terminal, from gnome. I wrote the following desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Screen
Comment=Use the command line
Keywords=shell;prompt;command;commandline;cmd;
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal --window --full-screen -e 'screen -x autoscreen'
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
```

Every time I run this desktop entry, the new gnome terminal with gnu-`screen` session starts. But, I would like to switch to the already running window, not start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what i did exactly, but this works properly

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Screen
Comment=Use the command line
Keywords=shell;prompt;command;commandline;cmd;
TryExec=screen
Exec=gnome-terminal  --full-screen --class gnome-terminal-server -e 'screen -x autoscreen'
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
StartupWMClass=gnome-terminal-server
```